# Request continue even after redirect through Django Middleware

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-middleware

I have created custom Middleware in `users/middleware.py` file. Till yesterday, the request was terminating after middleware return HttpResponseRedirect. but today the request keeps continuing and reloads the profile page. below is my middleware.py file.  I am using `Django 2.1.7`

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
import pytz
from django.urls import reverse_lazy , reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse ,HttpResponseRedirect


class TimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.session['timezone'] = 'Asia/Kolkata'
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))

class CheckProfileMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self,request):
        if request.user.first_name == "" or request.user.last_name == "":

            if 'profile' not in request.path_info:
                request.session['is_incomplete']=1
                # return HttpResponse("ok")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile')) 
        else:
            request.session['is_incomplete']=0
            return None
```

basically I want to redirect the user to the profile page if his profile is incomplete. below are my middleware in `setings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'users.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'users.middleware.CheckProfileMiddleware',
]
```

When I use `return HttpResponse` it stops execution but it continue execution on `HttpResponseRedirect`

here is my URLConf.

```
path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
```

my view.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user= User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f' Your Profile has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        context={
            'profile' : profile,
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form,
            'users':user,
        }
        return render(request,'profile.html', context)
```

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))` -- you're redirecting to the `profile` view.

Comment: yes, I am redirecting to profile view so that the user's details and form get pre-populated from that view and that redirects to profile page. This was working on another PC yesterday. But don't know what happened today?

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying the redirection is not working or something else? In any way, add your URLConf please.

Comment: Yes, redirection working completely fine but it keeps repeating not get terminated once it complete.

Comment: Does `profile` send a correct `HttpResponse`?

Comment: yes my  `profile view`  is rendering correct response

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `profile` view.

Comment: added `profile` view

Comment: Thanks @heemayl for your efforts to help me. actually i found the solution and posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. The culprit was AJAX request. On each page AJAX is called simultaneously with page load. So whenever AJAX is called Middleware was considering as GET request and again redirects to `profile` view. So I put the condition in Middleware to avoid if it is an AJAX request. my updated `middleware.py`

```
class CheckProfileMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self,request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not request.path.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL):
                if request.user.first_name == "" or request.user.last_name == "":
                    if ('profile' not in request.path_info) and (not request.is_ajax()):
                        request.session['is_incomplete']=1
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile')) 
                else:
                    request.session['is_incomplete']=0
```